# Counting rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: arrays

I've been searching for a way to fill in column 'H' and 'I' of the attached image.

For 'H' I need to count every time the date and date shipped out don't equal for each item. It will be something like this:
(A:A <> D:D, B:B = $G$2, E:E <> "Base Inventory")

The second equation is to calculate the average lead time for each item:
Average(E:E - D:D) where B:B = $G$2, and D:D = "Complete" while ignoring rows with blanks

The table is much larger than the image and I can't use a helper row.

Thanks.

[Example Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaE7Y.png)

Comment: Why no helper row? This may not be possible with an excel formula without one. You could write a custom macro to do it (is that ok), or you can use helper rows to make it fairly easy.

Comment: I can't use a helper row because there's no real end to the table. When I applied the formula to the entire column it maxed out my computers performance.

Comment: I think I solved part of it: Cell H2 =SUMPRODUCT((A:A <>D:D) * (B:B = G2)) - COUNTIFS(C:C, "Base Inventory",B:B, G2)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, shipping calc, I wrote a function that will compute it for you:

```
Public Function Shippingcalc(item1 As Range, codes As Range, date2 As Range, shipped As Range, status As Range)
    Dim Count As Integer
    Count = 0

    For n = 1 To codes.Rows.Count
        If status.Cells(n, 1).Value <> "Base Inventory" Then
            If codes.Cells(n, 1).Value = item1.Cells(1, 1).Value Then
                If shipped.Cells(n, 1).Value <> 0 Then
                    If shipped.Cells(n, 1).Value <> date2.Cells(n, 1).Value Then
                        Count = Count + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next n

    Shippingcalc = Count
End Function
```

You have to implement that as a macro and macro-enable the workbook.
Then the function in H would look something like:

```
=Shippingcalc(G2, B$2:B$10, A$2:A$10, D$2:D$10, C$2:C$10)
```

And you can copy that (of course updating to the full column size).
Something similar should work for the other computation.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this morning while I was taking a poop, the equation for lead time came to me. It was way simpler than I imagined and goes back to high school math.

Average = (SUM(Received date) - SUM(Shipped date)) / Total

=(SUMIFS(E:E,B:B, G2,D:D,"<>",E:E,"<>") - SUMIFS(D:D,B:B, G2,D:D,"<>",E:E,"<>")) / (COUNTIFS(B:B, Q14, D:D,"<>",E:E,"<>")+1)

Thanks for your help guys.